# Excel VBA - Sum rows/columns in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, vba

Let's say that we have a 4x5 array. How can I sum get a separate 1D array with 5 elements where every element represents the column-sum of elements from the first array?

Comment: Is there any code that you've tried so far so we can see where you've gone wrong? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If done in the spreadsheet**

I think I understand your question. At the bottom of each column simply put a SUM equation and sum over only the numbers in that column. For example if your array is in A1:E4 (first five columns and first four rows) put the following in cell A5:

```
=SUM(A1:A4)
```

And then copy cell A5 into cells B5 to E5.

**EDIT - If done in VBA**

```
Dim Arr_1(1 to 4, 1 to 5) as Double
Dim Arr_2(1 to 5) as Double
For col = 1 to 5
    Arr_2(col) = 0
    for row = 1 to 4
        Arr_2(col) = Arr_2(col) + Arr_1(row, col)
    Next row
Next col
```

Comment: Row 5 is then your desired 1D array

Comment: Yes, you understand it fairly rigtht. But the thing is that I want to deal only with arrays, no cell values. So the 2D array is just an array and I want to make a new array (not written in cells) with the sums

Comment: Great, this code is what I was looking for. Thank you, user1228123!

Answer (score 2):

The code sums the column of YourArray; for sum of the row switch 0 and 1

```
 With Application.WorksheetFunction
       sum_array = .sum(.Index(YourArray(), 0, 1)) 'switch 0 and 1 for row
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Arr_1(1 to 4, 1 to 5) as Double
Dim Arr_2(1 to 5) as Double
For col = 1 to 5
    Arr_2(col) = 0
    for row = 1 to 4
        Arr_2(col) = Arr_2(col) + Arr_1(row, col)
    Next row
Next col
```

Thank you, user1228123!